# Loading wordpress menu in an external server

Tags: menus

The scenario is like, I have two servers:

- Server A : Hosts WordPress
- Server B : Hosts Some PHP Scripts

Now, I want to load the wordpress menu on **server B**. Is there any way to achieve this? Couldn't find anything helpful.

I have a plan like this, so far:

- Save the complete output of `wp_nav_menu()` in the wordpress **option table**
- From Server B, connect to wordpress database **remotely** and get the value of the menu from option table, and print that on the PHP page, wrapping with css from the wordpress theme.

Is there any good approach than what I have planned?

Comment: That's about as good as it gets. There is no API or anything to server menus remotely.

Comment: Another option for anyone in a similar situation but unable to connect to the database remotely would be to save the output of `wp_nav_menu()` to a publicly available html file and include it on Server B using `file_get_contents` (assuming `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on Server B).